# Reducibility over $\mathbb Q$ implies reducibility over $\mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$. If $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q$, then it is reducible over $\mathbb Z$.

I went through the proof from the book I'm reading, which starts as follows:

We're given $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q$ , so we can write  $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ where $h(x),g(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$.

Now the next statement says - ***"Clearly, we may assume that $f(x)$ is primitive because we can divide both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by the content of $f(x)$."***

How is that ? When we write  $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, how can we conclude that content of $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ ? It divides $f(x)$, that's obvious, but $g(x)$ ? How ?

Let's say the content of $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$, then how can we conclude that $f(x)$ is primitive ? Can anyone explain ?

Comment: $g\in\Bbb Q[x]$, so you can divide $g$ by any non-zero integer and get another polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$. They didn't say that if the content of $f$ divides $g$ then $f$ is primitive! They said we can assume $f$ is primitive. This is clear; if $c$ is the content of $f$ and $f=gh$ as above then $f/c$ is primitive and $f/c=(g/c)h$.

Comment: I got the point you've stated. Thanks for that. But why the proof is so specific to a primitive polynomial ? Why this 'primitive' assumption is considered ? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: The answer to that is somewhere in the rest of the proof! They _use_ the fact that $f$ is primitive at some point...